# Laravel Populate Drop-down list of countries using Form Collective using array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, drop-down-menu

Im new to laravel and I want to populate my dropdown list using Form Collectives in Laravel

> Fore example, Here is my array of countries

```
<?php 
    $countries = array("AF" => "Afghanistan",
    "AL" => "Albania",
    "DZ" => "Algeria",
    "AS" => "American Samoa",
    "AD" => "Andorra",
    "AO" => "Angola")
?>
```

Here is my Form-Collective "Select / Dropdown"

> Using Form Collective

```
   {{Form::select('country',  '', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Country...'])}}
```

So how can i do it? Anyone who would like to help me, I appreciate it thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in the Form collective select function receives an array of values that you want to be displayed, so simply pass your array, and change `{{` with `{!!` which escapes the HTML output instead of printing it out as text.

```
   {!! Form::select('country',  $countries, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Country...']) !!}
```

--- EDIT

If you don't have an admin panel from which you enter a country, then the simplest way with which I will go is store the countries in a language file. For example:

in `resources/lang/en/countries.php`

```
return [
   "AF" => "Afghanistan",
   "AL" => "Albania",
   "DZ" => "Algeria",
   "AS" => "American Samoa",
   "AD" => "Andorra",
   "AO" => "Angola"
];
```

then in your view:

```
{!! Form::select('country',  trans('countries'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Country...']) !!}
```

Comment: It does not work :( . I think there's something wrong or It needed to add something

Comment: @SummerWinter How are you passing the array, or what error do you get? Have you tried inline if it will work, such as this

`{!! Form::select('country',  ["AF" => "Afghanistan", "AL" => "Albania"], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Country...']) !!}`

Comment: Yeah it work like that .. but im just wondering if there's a short way on how to generate or store the array like the simplest and practical way

Comment: It does work !! thank you for helping beginners like me